# Integral in mean field theory

Tags: statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, integration, mean-field-theory

Using MFT, I have obtained energy spectrum of a model to be:

$$\mathcal{E}_k (m_0,\tilde m_e)=\sqrt{{(J_b \cdot m_o + J_a \cdot m_e)^2 + \frac{{J_p^2}}{{16}} \cdot \cos^2(k)}}
$$

Now, in order to obtain a self consistency equation I need to find total energy

$$E=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}dk \mathcal{E}_k (m_0,\tilde m_e)$$
(Note: B.Z. is from $-\pi/2$ to $\pi/2$).

and then for self consistency equation:

$$\frac{\partial E}{\partial m_o}=0,\quad\frac{\partial E}{\partial \tilde m_e}=0.$$

But, I am unable to integral to obtain $E$ (I've tried in Mathematica also). Is there any way to solve it?

Comment: Evaluating an integral is a question about math, not physics. *Mathematica*  gives me a result in terms of elliptic integrals.

Comment: Are you just looking for the integral of $\sqrt{a+b\cos^2(\phi)}$ over $\phi$ from $-\pi/2$ to $\pi/2$ where $a$ and $b$ are independent of $\phi$?